# Automate multiple password enties to decrypted LUKS + Ext4 USB stick

Tags: shell-script, password, encryption, ext4, luks

I have a USB stick encrypted with LUKS + Ext4.  I have forgotten the password...

However, I know which words will be included in the password and have a list of all permutations of those words.  About 10,000 permutations.

Instead of me trying each and every permutation 1 by 1 manually (which will be a long, slow, and painfully tedious process), is it possible to automate this process?  I know this sounds like some sort of malicious brute force attack, but it's not.  If I wanted something like that, I could have easily downloaded some dodgy software from the internet.

Instead, I want to use something which is safe on my computer, a script (or any safe solution) which is custom built for me specifically.

Is this possible?

Comment: you just have to pipe it to `cryptsetup luksOpen` with the right syntax and note that (as written many times in the manual) when it's automated from stdin, you musn't include a trailing LF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in the most naive case you can roughly do something like

```
for a in 'fo' 'foo' 'fooo'
do
    for b in 'ba' 'bar' 'baar'
    do
        for c in 'bz' 'baz' 'bazz'
        do
            echo -n "$a$b$c" | cryptsetup open /dev/luks luks \
            && echo "'$a$b$c' is the winner!" \
            && break 3
        done
    done
done
```

and it goes through all the puzzle pieces ... foobarbz foobarbaz foobarbazz ... etc. in order. (If you have optional pieces, add '' empty string. If your pieces are in random order, well, think about it yourself).

To optimize performance, you can:

- patch `cryptsetup` to keep reading passphrases from stdin (lukscrackplus on github for one such example but it's dated)
- generate the complete list of words, `split` it into separate files, and run multiple such loops (one per core, perhaps even across multiple machines)
- compile cryptsetup with a different/faster crypto backend (e.g. nettle instead of gcrypt), difference was huge last time I benchmarked it
- find a different implementation meant to bruteforce LUKS

But it's probably pointless to optimize if you have either too little (can go through in a day w/o optimizing) or way too many possibilities (no amount of optimizing will be successful).

At the same time, check:

- are you using the wrong keyboard layout?
- is the LUKS header intact?

(with LUKS1 there is no way to know for sure, but if you `hexdump -C` it and there is no random data where it should be, no need to waste time then)

There's also a similar question here: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/128539

But if you're really able to narrow it down by a lot, the naive approach works too.

Comment: hexdump -C /dev/sdd returns a lot of data.  Not sure where I am supposed to look for random data.

Comment: for reference, `truncate -s 8M foobar.img`; `cryptsetup luksFormat foobar.img`; `hexdump -C foobar.img` would show you what an intact header looks like (with nothing else on it). Where this has random data, your sdd would also have random data at the same address

Comment: @frostschutz, thank you very much for your suggestions.  Actually helped me find my passphrase!  Added bounty just to say thank you, but unable to give it just yet, will have to wait 24 hours.

Answer (score 4):

The most efficient way to perform this attack is to use John the Ripper's [luks2john](https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper/blob/bleeding-jumbo/run/luks2john.py) to extract the hash, and then attack it with John ('LUKS' hash format) or hashcat (hash mode 14600).

This has the advantage of scaling up to the number of cores (with either John CPU support or hashcat OpenCL CPU support) or the number of GPUs (with hashcat OpenCL GPU support) that you have.

It also takes advantage of any attack-side cryptographic efficiencies that are faster than using the native interface. These efficiencies can sometimes be dramatically faster than simply trying a normal unlock over and over again.

This also gives you the full suite of attack modes that those tools support (wordlist, rules, mask, hybrid, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I had almost this exact problem. I wrote a script that looped through all the possibilities until one worked. Mine was a `truecrypt` volume though. The only problem would be if there was some rate limiting but that would only be the case if you were passing off the check to a website or the like. With the volume in your possession it is relatively easy to do this.

But also this is very much brute forcing. You have just narrowed the choices to a small number so it won't be difficult to do.

Comment: Could you script be adapted to work with LUKS encrypted drives?  Yes, I have the USB stick in my possession.

Comment: I'm not sure I even have the script anymore. But all you need to do is have the list of words, capitalization, order, whatever else you are changing and make a nested loop to run through them. Then you just need to be able to call the decryption command with the password. You should be able to do this with any scripting language: I used `perl` but `python` or `bash` would also probably be pretty easy.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as previous answers, the `hashcat` is one of the best options. As the LUKS doesn't storage any hashes, we need to get an encrypted data sample (header) from your USB drive. We going to work on that sample only.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/{USB_LUKS_partition} of=/tmp/data_sample.luks bs=512 count=4079
```

`Hashcat` has many options to cracking a password, from straight bruteforcing to dictionary attacks, rule based attacks and mask attacks. In this scenario, we have password_candidates.txt:

```
hashcat -m 14600 -a 0 -w 3 /tmp/data_sample.luks password_candidates.txt
```

This should give you your password within seconds. 
G/L